# function is a fourier transform for integrable function

Tags: analysis, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

I have this example as an application to Bernstein`s Lemma, and I`m confused because I`m actually not able to find the lemma in any book that I have. So I would appreciate it if you at least give me a reference to the lemma and explain this to me. 
$$ g(\xi)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c} (1-\vert \xi \vert^2)^{\alpha} , \vert \xi \vert \le1\\
0  , \vert \xi \vert >1 \end{array}
\right. $$
when is $g \in \mathscr F L^1 $?

similarly $h(\xi)=(1+\vert \xi \vert ^2 )^{-\epsilon}$ when this is  a fourier transform of some function in $L^1$ if $\epsilon >0$ ?

Comment: So you meant $g = \hat{f}$. You can use that both $\hat{f}$ and $\hat{f}'$  are  $L^2$, thus both $f$ and $2i \pi x f(x)$ are $L^2$.

Comment: how can I use this to find when the function is a fourier transform for some function in $l^1$ in $R^n$ ? I would assume that there is a condition containing n?

Comment: I edited the question actually. I just discovered that I wrote it wrong.